semiconductor supply chain flowchart
I need to recreate a flowchart as faithfully as possible to the one depicted in the image. Unfortunately, my knowledge of LaTeX is still basic, and with the lines of code I have written, we are not even close to what I want. Thanks in advance.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!50]
\tikzstyle{input} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
    % Nodes
    \node (R&D) [process] {Research and Development};
    \node (EDA) [process, below of=R&D, yshift=-0.5cm] {Electronic Design Automation and Core IP};
    \node (Equip) [process, below of=EDA, yshift=-0.5cm] {Semiconductor Manufacturing Equipment};
    \node (Materials) [process, right of=Equip, xshift=2cm] {Materials};
    \node (Design) [process, right of=EDA, xshift=5cm] {Design};
    \node (Fab) [process, right of=Equip, xshift=5cm] {Fabrication};
    \node (Assembly) [process, right of=Materials, xshift=5cm] {Assembly, Testing, and Packaging};
    \node (EndUse) [process, right of=Assembly, xshift=3cm] {End Use};

    % Titles
    \node (Inputs) [below of=Equip, yshift=-1cm] {Inputs to Chip Production};
    \node (Production) [above of=Design, yshift=2cm] {Chip Production};
    \node (IDM) [process2, above of=Production, yshift=0.5cm, xshift=-1cm] {Integrated Device Manufacturer};
    \node (Fabless) [process2, left of=IDM, xshift=-1cm] {Fabless};
    \node (Foundry) [process2, right of=IDM, xshift=1cm] {Foundry};
    \node (OSAT) [process2, right of=Foundry, xshift=1cm] {OSAT};

    % Arrows
    \draw [arrow] (R&D) -- (Design);
    \draw [arrow] (R&D) -- (EDA);
    \draw [arrow] (EDA) -- (Design);
    \draw [arrow] (EDA) -- (Fab);
    \draw [arrow] (Equip) -- (Fab);
    \draw [arrow] (Materials) -- (Fab);
    \draw [arrow] (Fab) -- (Assembly);
    \draw [arrow] (Assembly) -- (EndUse);
    
    \draw [arrow] (Design) -- (Fab);
    \draw [arrow] (Fab) -- (Assembly);

    \draw [arrow] (IDM) -- (Design);
    \draw [arrow] (Fabless) -- (Design);
    \draw [arrow] (Foundry) -- (Fab);
    \draw [arrow] (OSAT) -- (Assembly);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Have a look at the matrix library and just the main coverage of matrix in the manual. (I would answer, but @Qrrbrbirlbel will be too fast.)

See comments in the code for a few remarks.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,          % for arrow tips
  calc,                 % for $ syntax (coordinate calculation)
  ext.positioning-plus, % for … = of -(…)(…) and … = .5:of …
                        %   loads the positioning library
  ext.paths.ortho,      % for |- and -| shortcuts
  graphs}               % for nice graphs syntax
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=.5cm and 1.5cm, >=Latex, thick,
  adjust matrix area/.style args={#1#2#3}{
    insert path={([shift={(#1.25em,#2.25em)}]#3)}},
  singleline box/.style={minimum width=+8em, text depth=+.1\baselineskip},
  multiline box/.style={singleline box, minimum height=+5em, align=center},
  gray box/.style={draw, fill=gray!10},
  blue box/.style={draw, fill=blue!50!black, text=white, multiline box},
  magenta box/.style={draw, fill=magenta!70!black, text=white, singleline box},
  every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+.5em}
]
\matrix[gray box] (cp) {
  \tikzset{name prefix=cp+}
  \path[nodes=blue box]
    node(Design) {Design}
    node[right=of Design] (Fabric) {Fabrication}
    node[right=of Fabric] (Assemb) {Assembly,\\Testing, and\\Packaging};
  \path[nodes=magenta box]
    node[above=of Design] (Fables) {Fabless}
    node[above=of Fabric] (Foundr) {Foundry}
    node[above=of Assemb] (OSAT)   {OSAT}
    % The -(A)(B) syntax is part of ext.positioning-plus
    % and sets the node's width as wide as A and B encompass
    node[above=of -(Fables)(OSAT)] (IDM) {Integrated Device Manufacturer};
  % The .5: syntax is part of ext.positioning-plus
  % and multiplies the set node distance by the factor of .5
  \node[above=.5:of IDM] (cp) {Chip Production}
    [adjust matrix area/.list={--Design.south west, +-Assemb.south east}];
  \\};
\matrix[gray box, below=of cp] (icp) {
  \tikzset{name prefix=icp+}
  \path[nodes=blue box]
    node                  (EDAC) {Electronic\\Design\\Automation and\\Core IP}
    node[right=of EDAC]   (SME)  {Semiconductor\\Manufacturing\\Equipment}
    node[right=of SME]    (Matr) {Materials};
  \node[below=.5:of SME] (icp) {Inputs to Chip Production}
    [adjust matrix area/.list={-+EDAC.north west, ++Matr.north east}];
  \\};
% The ($…$) syntax is from the calc library,
% see https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.5.3
\coordinate (cpicp-west) at ($(cp.south west)!.5!(icp.north west)$)
 coordinate (cpicp-east) at ($(cp.south east)!.5!(icp.north east)$);
\node[left =of cpicp-west, blue box] (RandD) {Research and\\Development};
\node[right=of cpicp-east, gray box, multiline box] (EndUse) {End Use};

\graph[use existing nodes, /tikz/ortho/install shortcuts]{
  cp+Design ->     cp+Fabric -> cp+Assemb ->[-|] EndUse,
  icp+EDAC  ->     cp+Design,
  icp+SME   ->     {cp+Fabric, cp+Assemb, icp+Matr},
  icp+Matr  ->     {cp+Fabric, cp+Assemb},
  RandD     ->[|-] {cp, icp}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output

